# What might be the reason for this flag to be marked as disputed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, flagging

I'm talking about this flag.

[image]

Clearly, the OP wants an answer that explains that formula intuitively without expanding. [The answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4184049/730361) just expands the formula which the OP doesn't want. So, it's not an answer. What might be the reason for being marked 'disputed'?

Comment: Related LQ review [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1623364).

Comment: I flagged again as very low quality. Not sure what would happen (will it enters the LW review queue again?)

Comment: @ArcticChar I just checked; looks like no, maybe (wild guess) it goes into a queue of disputed flags for mods to look at

Comment: @calvinkhor The result of the flag is :  declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention. Look like the system treat it as if I choose "in need of moderator intervention"

Comment: I wonder what would happen if I flag it as "not an answer" now....

Comment: The answer appears to be deleted now.

Comment: @ArcticChar It won't; posts only appear in the queue once. It will go to moderators.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a very literal answer to the question: most flags that aren't explicitly for moderator attention are dealt with in the review queues by users of the site who have access to those queues. That means other users are the jury here, which puts you at their mercy. In this case, three users said that it looked okay, while two voted for deletion. Three "looks okay" votes are enough to finish the review in this case.

Getting in to why three users voted that it looked okay is a whole other thing. We won't know unless they share their reasoning, and there are lots of different potential explanations (disagreed, thought it was bad but did not merit deletion, didn't see the issue, cat ran over keyboard, etc).